# Application of finding shortest paths on Cayley graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, coding-theory, permutation-groups

For a fixed integer number $m$, Consider Cayley graph defined by all m-cycles in Symmetric group $Sym(n)$.
I know that for $m=2$, 
there are some applications of finding shortest paths (or distance function) on these Cayley graphs in the Coding theory and Computational biology.
Is there any application for $m>2$ ?